# How to have files appear in alphanumeric order? E.g. 09, 0A, 0B, 10, not 0A, 0B, 09, 10

Tags: filesystem, filename

When I use both numbers and letters in filenames, they do not appear in the correct order.
Correct example:
00.jpg
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg
06.jpg
07.jpg
08.jpg
09.jpg
0A.jpg
0B.jpg
10.jpg

Instead, they appear like this:
0A.jpg
0B.jpg
00.jpg
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg
06.jpg
07.jpg
08.jpg
09.jpg
10.jpg

How do I get letters to come after numbers, like in hexadecimal (that's where I got the idea)?
Is there a setting I can change, or is this just an inherent feature of Ubuntu?

Comment: Which application are you talking about? It depends on how the application handles it. Some may allow you to change it, others not.

Comment: "an inherent feature of Ubuntu". No that is a feature of GNU Linux/POSIX. Not Ubuntu `LANG=C ls` does an alphabetical sort on command line

Comment: @Sebastian No apps, just directories, such as what you see when you go to Home/Documents.

Comment: That is also an app :) So you mean the default file manager in your Ubuntu distribution (which you did not specify by the way)?

Comment: Yes, the default file manager.